# CSS Code Splitting with Webpack 2 and React Router

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, css-modules, extract-text-plugin

I'm code splitting my JavaScript files with React Router and Webpack 2 like this:

```
export default {
  path: '/',
  component: Container,
  indexRoute: {
    getComponent(location, cb) {
      if (isAuthenticated()) {
        redirect();
      } else {
        System.import('../landing-page/LandingPage')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
       }
    },
  },
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'login',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('../login/Login')
          .then(loadRoute(cb))
          .catch(errorLoading);
      },
    },
    { /* etc */ 
    }
};
```

Which results on this bundle:

```
public/
  vendor.bundle.js
  bundle.js
  0.bundle.js
  1.bundle.js
  2.bundle.js
```

Which means that the final user is getting only the JavaScript that he/she needs, according to the route that he/she is in.

**The thing is: for the css part, I'm not finding any resource to do same thing, which is to split the CSS according the user's needs.**

Is there a way to do it with Webpack 2 and React Router?

Comment: Did you see the documentation for CSS code splitting? https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-css/

Comment: @JakobLind yes I did. In the docs, the only was is to have multiple entries. But how can I have multiple entries, if I'm using React Router and there's only one entry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done. You'll need `CommonsChunkPlugin` in addition to `ExtractTextPlugin`. Also, define multiple entry points

```
entry: {
    A: "./a",
    B: "./b",
    C: "./c",
},
```

and configure `ExtractTextPlugin` to use entry point names as CSS file names

```
new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "[name].css"
}),
```

See a full example here:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-entry-points-commons-chunk-css-bundle

Comment: Is there an example with React Router, I don't think this is going to work in my case.

Comment: react-router has nothing to do with how CSS bundles are generated.

Comment: How can I put multiple entry points, if right now React Router is the single entry point of my application?

Answer (score 2):

While I may not answer your question **how to split css files so that only the necessary ones are loaded** the way you want the question to be answered (no plugin or that sort of thing), I hope to give you a possible alternative.

[`styled-components`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) use the new ES6 feature [tagged template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to style the components inside the javascript file. I think using this library would solve your problem of loading only the necessary css files, because there would be no more css files per se.

[`react-boilerplate`](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) [chose `styled-components` over sass](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/docs/css/sass.md), because

> `styled-components` have a more powerful approach: instead of trying
>   to give a styling language programmatic abilities, it pulls logic and
>   configuration out into JS these features belong.

So using `styled-components` would not only solve your problem of loading only the necessary css, but it would further add to the decoupling of your application, makes it easier to test the design and reason about your app.

Here's the [live demo](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KeeZCr0xKfutOfOujxN) where you can experiment with the `styled-components` and check how it works.